# How to Add UIButton Inline with UILabel Text

Tags: uilabel, nstextattachment

I have been trying to figure out how to add a  `UIButton` inline with the text of a `UILabel`, such as in the following image taken from the iCloud Backup settings view:

[image: Image of iCloud Backup settings view]

The only way that I can think of is by using `NSTextAttachment` by formatting the text to behave like a `UIButton`. Is that my only option?